# download file sftp with curl running out of memory

Tags: php, curl, sftp

How to avoid this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted
```

The files are very large (over 5gb)

```
$host = 'domain.com';
$pass = 'xxx';

$remote = "sftp://root:$pass@$host/var/www/test.txt";
$local = 'C:\wamp\www\test.txt';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remote);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "root:$pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
file_put_contents($local, curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [CURLOPT_FILE option](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). It will write the data directly to the given file.